# Fix parameters in calibration

Tags: quantlib

How can I fix some of the model parameters passed to optimizer?

in Heston calibration I want to fix two parameters (initial variance and mean reversion) and run Levenberg Marquardt optimization routine to find the remaining three (as in Janek & Wystup's  [FX Smile in The Heston Model](https://authors.repec.org/pro/pja286/))

e.g. in below example from testsuite/hestonmodel.cpp is there a way to hold some of the params constant?

```
void HestonModelTest::testDAXCalibration() {

...

const boost::shared_ptr<HestonProcess> process(
    boost::make_shared<HestonProcess>(
        riskFreeTS, dividendTS, s0, v0, kappa, theta, sigma, rho));

const boost::shared_ptr<HestonModel> model(
    boost::make_shared<HestonModel>(process));

const boost::shared_ptr<PricingEngine> engines[] = {
    boost::make_shared<AnalyticHestonEngine>(model, 64),
};

const Array params = model->params();
for (Size j=0; j < LENGTH(engines); ++j) {
    model->setParams(params);
    for (Size i = 0; i < options.size(); ++i)
        options[i]->setPricingEngine(engines[j]);

    LevenbergMarquardt om(1e-8, 1e-8, 1e-8);
    model->calibrate(options, om,
                     EndCriteria(400, 40, 1.0e-8, 1.0e-8, 1.0e-8));
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

added ***fixParameters*** boolean vector as the last argument in **calibrate()** call and it  fixed the 2 parameters as expected. I.e. calibration was done on the 3 free params only.

In *fixParameters* vector set *true* the params to be held fixed , e.g.
*kappa* (the second arg) and *v0* (the last arg) and others as false.

also add default *constraint* and *weight* args in to complete the *calibrate()* signature:

```
Constraint constraint = Constraint();
std::vector<Real> weights = std::vector<Real>();
std::vector<bool> fixParameters = { false, true, false, false, true };
model->calibrate(options, om, endCriteria, constraint, weights, fixParameters);
```

the order of arguments is from ql/HestonModel.cpp:

```
 /*HestonModel.cpp args: 
// variance mean version level
Real theta() const { return arguments_[0](0.0); }
// variance mean reversion speed
Real kappa() const { return arguments_[1](0.0); }
// volatility of the volatility
Real sigma() const { return arguments_[2](0.0); }
// correlation
Real rho()   const { return arguments_[3](0.0); }
// spot variance
Real v0()    const { return arguments_[4](0.0); }*/
```